# rocketmq-cpp fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Tags: visual-studio-2017, rocketmq

I  am  generating rocketmq dll  from rocketmq-cpp  opensource github Project.I  have  used folling Prequisite
boost 1.56.0,-->  have  build  using this jam.exe msvc architecture=x86 address-model=64 link=static runtime-link=static stage(which  is  64  bit builded)
Cmake 3.9.3
so,i  have  build  rocketmq-cpp   using  cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" it  will  generate Project but  whenEver  i  am  building  project  it  always  shows Error 
libboost_thread-vc140-mt-s-1_56.lib(thread.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
But  when  i  have  changed boost 1.56.0  to   build using  32  bit after  that  i  am  getting  Error 
fatal error LNK1112 libboost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_58 not  found .i  am  not  able  to  find  how  visual  studio  searching  for libboost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_58  which  is  not  there in boost 1.56.0/stage/lib.i  have  used

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have boost 1.56.0 built as a 64-bit library, when building `rocketmq-cpp`, you have to make sure to also use the 64-bit generator for Visual Studio. After clearing you existing build directory, try using `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` (note the `Win64` prefix)

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2015%202017.html

Comment: I  have  tried  your  solution but  whenEver its  building  from visualstudio it  always  getting  this  Error LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_atomic-vc120-mt-s-1_56.lib'  since i  have libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-s-1_56 in  boost/stage/lib  i  dont  know  whey  visual studio searching  for  wrong  libs

Comment: Could you confirm you built the boost libraries using VS2017 and not VS2013 ? In other word, before running `jam.exe` which visual studio terminal did you open ? 

Updating your post indicating how boost is built would be helpful too. (all steps from checking the source, to configuring and build should probably be listed)

Comment: build and install boost 1.56.0,following build options are needed to be set when run in  VisualStudio Developer 2017 
bjam.exe: msvc architecture=x86 address-model=64 link=static runtime-link=static stage
after  builded <boostHome>/stage/lib/*.lib files
Navigate to rocketmq-cpp build  in  visual studio 2017  developer Command 
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..
Then open  Build  Project in  visual  studio  2017 and  build  the PRoject it  giveserror LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_atomic-vc120-mt-s-1_56.lib'